# Fusión de etiquetas swing y java-swing

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Solicitud de Fusión de etiquetas [swing](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) y [java-swing](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-swing).

Ambas etiquetas hablan de lo mismo, incluso tienen un descripción muy parecida.

En el sitio en ingles la principal es **swing** aunque no se que vote la comunidad :)

Comment: Esperemos a ver qué dice la comunidad para luego hacer la fuuu-sión

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fusión realizada. La etiqueta [swing](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) es la principal.

Comment: Muchas gracias sr ♦

Comment: Luiggi, te faltó agregar la imagen: http://i.imgur.com/b0xPisW.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Voto a favor de la fusión. En todo caso ya que no hay riesgo de confundirla con otra tecnología y por simetría con el sitio en inglés personalmente prefiero la etiqueta [swing](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)